# Brexit - What happens to EU citizens holding EEA Registration Certificate

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, eu-citizens, eu-spouses, brexit

*Please note this is not a duplicate question to the other one here [Other similar question.](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8593/the-uk-has-voted-to-leave-the-eu-how-does-this-affect-eu-nationals-living-worki)*

Since the results are out confirming Brexit, what would happen to EU citizens currently wokring and leaving in UK and holding a [EEA Registration Certificate document](https://www.gov.uk/eea-registration-certificate)

This document confirms the right to work for an EU national living in UK, but I assume this is issued under EEA laws and not UK laws.

Also, what about family members of EEA national having EEA Residence Card?

Comment: nobody knows yet

Comment: The answer for all of these questions are: nobody knows yet. Hence this is still duplicate.