# Does a Romanian senior citizen ( pensioner) need a special visa to permanently live in UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, residency, brexit

We are interested to know if one of our family members who is an old senior from Romania can permanently live with us in the UK. Does Brexit impose any restrictions?

Comment: Currently there are no restrictions on this, but that may well change. At the moment nobody really knows. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8593/the-uk-has-voted-to-leave-the-eu-how-does-this-affect-uk-eu-and-other-citizen has lots of relevant information that covers this scenario and others. I'm going to vote for closing this as a duplicate of that item.

Answer (score 1):

There is no visa required at this time. Brexit has not occurred yet.

Answer (score 1):

Free movement remains in place during the transition period. So as an EU citizen he can come and live in the UK as long as he arrives before the end of 2020.

If he wants to remain in the UK long term, he will need to apply to the EU settlement scheme. Initially he should be granted "pre-settled" status. He will then later need to apply again to get settled status once he has lived in the UK for 5 years.